# Python: requests de SOAP, como fazer requisicões de um wsdl

Tags: python, wsdl, python-requests

Olá, eu tenho um wsdl (https://ws1.bmgconsig.com.br/webservices/SaqueComplementar?wsdl) e preciso fazer requisições, porém não sei como fazer o tratamento dos headers e body com base no wsdl.

o cabeçalho:

```
{'Date': 'Thu, 04 Apr 2019 12:17:42 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=utf-8', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Connection': 'close', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
```

meu código:

```
url = 'https://ws1.bmgconsig.com.br/webservices/SaqueComplementar?wsdl'
headers = {'input name': 'buscarLimiteSaqueRequest'}
params = {informações de login, senha e parâmetros necessários}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=params )
```

retorna:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
     <title>400 Bad Request</title>
     </head><body>
     <h1>Bad Request</h1>
     <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
     </p>
     <hr>
     <address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at slap443.bancobmg.com.br Port 80</address>
     </body></html>
```

Não sei se 'headers' está configurado certo. Eu já li toda a documentação do 'requests', porém ela da muitos exemplos em json(), mas esse wsdl não fornece suporte.

Se eu não coloco 'headers', retorna:

```
    <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
       <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
       <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
       <detail>
        <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">slap443.bancobmg.com.br</ns2:hostname>
       </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
     </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Eu já utilizei o framework zeep e funcionou, porém ele é MUITO lento, creio que usando 'requests' eu consiga uma melhor performance.

Answer (score 0):

Seu servidor está esperando um parâmetro SOAPAction no cabeçalho. No request ficaria:

```
url = 'https://ws1.bmgconsig.com.br/webservices/SaqueComplementar?wsdl'
headers = {'input name': 'buscarLimiteSaqueRequest', 'SOAPAction ': '<action>'}
params = {informações de login, senha e parâmetros necessários}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=params )
```

Mas nesse caso você precisa saber qual valor colocar no lugar de `<action>`.